# What does the data look like that is returned from a Model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

If I have the following models:

- **Galaxy** (has_many Star)
- **Star** (belongs_to Galaxy, has_many Planet)
- **Planet** (belongs_to Star)

Each model has a name property.

If I were to call `Galaxy.where(:name => "Milky Way")`

What would be returned?

I do not care specifically about what data you use in an example I just want to know what kind of object will be returned (array or hash or whatever) and how it will be structured.

Unfortunately I dont have a way (or know of anywhere online) to test RoR code.

I tried Googling and looked at the documentation [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html) but could not find this information. If it is documented somewhere and I missed it, please let me know.

Comment: An array of galaxy models (if any match) or an empty array.

Comment: As far as I can understand the docs, that method returns an `ActiveRecord::Relation` which seems to represent a query against the database. How it's structured is meant to be opaque, the important thing is that you can either build new queries from it, or iterate over the result objects.

Comment: (True, I over-simplified saying it's an array. It looks like one, even claims to be one. It isn't.)

Answer (score 1):

This is the guide you want: [Active Record Query Interface](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html). Read and prosper :)